# Samba login question

Tags: samba

I have a samba server set up with a couple of shares that I would like to access using authentication.  As an initial test I was able to set them up to allow guest access, then I disabled that, enabled the 'user' authentication, and added+enabled a user using smbpasswd.  I am unable to connect to the share from my windows machine, using the username@ipaddress for the username field.  The windows machine is connected to an AD domain, and wonder if that is causing any of the issues I am having.

here is the share configuration

```
[share]
comment = an example
path = /home/spowers/Public/share
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
write list = spowers
valid users = spowers
read only = no
create mask = 0755
```

In the samba logs I get:

> create_connection_server_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

> I am unable to connect to the share from my windows machine, **using the
>   username@ipaddress** for the username field

Enter `spowers` in the username text box to see if it works.

Comment: I am using the correct credential and IP I place of usernamr and ipaddress.  I was showing the pattern of information and not the literal value.

Comment: Which method you use to connect: \\IP? Why did you need **@ipaddress** for username?

Comment: \\ip\share
the reason for the @ipaddress is because I want authentication against the samba server, and not the domain my workstation is joined to.  That is equivalent notation to ipaddress\username.

Comment: observation, it does work correctly when the username/password matches my domain login, even though the server is not tied into the domain.  Maybe this is working with a ticket instead of the actual credential set....